# ! LaTex Error: File `forest.sty` not found

Tags: packages, winedt, forest

When I run a `tikz` code on my PC, the following error always stop me from producing the figure.

> ! LaTex Error: File `forest.sty` not
>   found

But my code is okay in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/djsztrndpbhm).  My LaTex on PC(win7) is WinEdt 6.0.

Does it mean my codes need a separate file: `forest.sty`. I googled it but ending  without finding  any `forest.sty` file, can anyone give me the one?

Comment: This means that you don't have `forest` package installed on your PC, or you installed it in a folder where latex is not looking at.

Comment: It looks like you're using windows. If you use MikTeX, start miktex package manager and install forest.

Comment: Then how do I fix this problem

Comment: Yes I use Windows 7

Comment: An alternative is to copy the forest.sty file from http://chocolatshalba.ch/files/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest.sty and paste it in your editor. Save the file as forest.sty in the folder where the latex file that is being worked on is located.

Comment: The information about Windows/WinEdt is almost irrelevant here. Do you use MikTeX or TeX Live? Both of these have package managers that you use to install packages, as Ignasi already mentioned. @Leucippus While that would work, it is better to install the package with a package manager. [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) is available in both TeX Live and MikTeX.

Comment: I don't know if my Latex is MikTeX or TeX Live, but I find my WinEdt have a folder named MikTeX, does it mean I used MikTeX?

Comment: @Leucippus I tried with your method, it has other wrong messages.

Comment: @WangyanLi If the errors are similar then Google those style files and do the same thing. If it is another type of error then you will have to state what the error is. What often happens is that when using someone else's code packages/style files are often missing, or set ups are different and it can be a lengthy task to find all the files and clear out errors. Once completed latex becomes fun again.

Comment: As @TorbjørnT. explained, ***that is not a good method***. You should install packages using your installation's package manager. Apart from anything else, that method will work only for your current document. Moreover, even for that document it may well break later in weird, wonderful and deeply mysterious ways.

Comment: Search in the start menu for *Package manager*. If you find a program called that, or *Package manager (Admin)* (I think that's what it's called) that looks like what you see in http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pkgmgt.html, then you have MikTeX.  Use that to install new packages.